# What do the letters 'p' and 'c' mean in mutation descriptions?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics

[Example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/RCV000020356/):

> NM_000525.3(KCNJ11):**c.** 67A>G ( **p.** Lys23Glu) AND Permanent neonatal diabetes mellitus

Does "p" stand for "polymorphism"?

What does the letter "c" stand for?

Comment: I think `c` refers to `cDNA` and `p` refers to protein. Similarly there is `g` which most likely refers to genomic DNA.

Comment: You could check the whole HGVS guideline http://varnomen.hgvs.org/ for explanations (also @WYSIWYG is right).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [HGVS guidelines](http://varnomen.hgvs.org/recommendations/general/), a letter prefix should be used to indicate the reference sequence used. Accepted prefixes are:

- “g.” for a genomic reference sequence
- “m.” for a mitochondrial reference sequence
- “c.” for a coding DNA reference sequence
- “n.” for a non-coding DNA reference sequence
- “r.” for an RNA reference sequence (transcript)
- “p.” for a protein reference sequence